# Paas Excel sheet data in array and send to model using Codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, phpexcel, codeigniter-3

I am using PHPExcel for uploading large amount data file. While uploading the excel sheet it display the error :

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

because I am sending data through foreach loop and it takes time for uploading. Now I want to send data in array form. I am using following code in **Controller file:**

```
    $inputFileName = $_FILES['SMSFile']['tmp_name']; 
                        $reader = ReaderFactory::create(Type::XLSX);
                        $reader->open($inputFileName);
                        $count = 1;

                        foreach ($reader->getSheetIterator() as $sheet) {
                            foreach ($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
                                if ($count > 1) { 
                                 $ddate=$row[4]->format('d-M-Y');
                                 $ddate1=$row[5]->format('d-M-Y');

                                    $arr[]= array(
                                                'DISTName' => $row[0],              
                                                'contactNo' => $row[1],
                                                'sepecification' => $row[2],    
                                                'POD' => $row[3],                                           
                                                'dispatchDate' => $ddate,
                                                'ExpectedDate' =>$ddate1                                                     
                                            );

                                $to=$row[1];    
                                $Distinct=  $row[0];
                                $sepecification =$row[2];
                                $poid = $row[3];
                                $dispatchDate = $ddate; 
                                $ExpectedDate = $ddate1;
                                $SMSUser = 'abx';
                                $password = 'abxx';
                                $sid = 'ABC';
                                $message = "Dear Sir,\nDist: $Distinct \nSepecification: $sepecification \nPOD: $poid \nDispatch Date: \n$dispatchDate \nExpected Delivery: \n$ExpectedDate";           


                                    $sendSMS = $this->SendSMS->sendSMS($SMSUser, $password, $message, $to, $sid);           

                                 }



                                $count++;

                            }

                        $reader->close(); 
                        }
```

**Model file**

```
  public static function sendSMS($user, $password, $message, $to, $sid) {
    $fl = 0;
    $gwid = 2;
    //Prepare you post parameters
    $postData = array(
        'user' => $user,
        'password' => $password,
        'msisdn' => $to,
        'sid' => $sid,
        'msg' => $message,
        'fl' => $fl,
        'gwid' => $gwid,
    );
    //API URL
    $url="http://sms.example.in:8080/abc/xyz.aspx";

    // init the resource
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData
    ));
    //Ignore SSL certificate verification
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    //get response
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    //Print error if any
    if(curl_errno($ch))
    {
        echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use blew code in controller.**

```
 set_time_limit(0);
 ini_set('MAX_EXECUTION_TIME', -1);
```